# Search and Filter any word regex in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, search, filter

I am creating a word filter for a FAQ, right now it works but only with the first word, what regular expression should I use to filter for any word?

I can't pass the words to pattern because they come from an advanced custom field in Wordpress.

I have tried many ways, but I am not a regex expert.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(".search-field").keyup(function() {
  var pattern = new RegExp(
    "^" + this.value.replace(/([\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"),
    "i"
  );

  $(".js-list-faq li a")
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
      return !!$(this).text().match(pattern);
    })
    .show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box--default">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="search--form--container">
          <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://scansup.local/">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Buscar:</span>
                <input type="search"class="search-field"placeholder="Buscar …"value=""name="s"
                />
              </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Buscar" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="faq__list-container">
        <ul class="js-list-faq">
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-1" style="display: inline;">Anim Collapsible Group Item #1
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-2" style="display: inline;">pariatur Collapsible Group Item #2
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-3" style="display: inline;">cliche Collapsible Group Item #3
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-4" style="display: inline;">reprehenderit Collapsible Group Item #4</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-5" style="display: inline;"
                >enim Collapsible Group Item #5
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-6" style="display: inline;">eiusmod Collapsible Group Item #6
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-7" style="display: inline;">eiusmode Collapsible Group Item #7
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-8" style="display: inline;">Collapsible Group Item #8</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-9" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #9</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-10" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #10</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-11" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #11</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#heading-12" style="display: inline;">Collapsible Group Item #12</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-13" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #13</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-14" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #14</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#heading-15" style="display: inline;"
                >Collapsible Group Item #15</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, "^" means everything that starts with that letter or word.

Use this instead:

```js
...

var pattern = new RegExp(
  this.value.replace(/([\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"), 'i'
);

...
```